# How to solve TypeError: function got multiple values for argument

Tags: python, typeerror

I have some code inside a class for a driver im creating, confused why im getting this error when set_voltage calls _send_command. Here is the exact code that causes the error:
TypeError: _send_command() got multiple values for argument 'value'

```
    def _send_command(command, value=None, value_type=None, minimum=None, maximum=None):
        if value:
            raise_for_type(value, value_type)
            raise_for_range(value, minimum=minimum, maximum=maximum)
            message = f"{command}{value}"
        else:
            message = command
        self._send(message)
        self.raise_for_system_error()
```

```
    def set_voltage(self, voltage: float):
        command = f"SOUR:VOLT:LEV:IMM:AMPL "
        self._send_command(command, value=voltage, value_type=float, minimum=self.VOLT_MIN, maximum=self.VOLT_MAX)
        return percent_error(self.get_voltage(), voltage) < 5
```

Comment: do you have an example of what's stored in your variable called voltage ?

Comment: its called with set_voltage(6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `self` argument which you need for class methods:

```
def _send_command(self, command, value=None, value_type=None, minimum=None, maximum=None):
    if value:
        raise_for_type(value, value_type)
        raise_for_range(value, minimum=minimum, maximum=maximum)
        message = f"{command}{value}"
    else:
        message = command
    self._send(message)
    self.raise_for_system_error()
```